# Encoding Username & Password in Office 365 URL

Tags: url, passwords

After messing around with it for an hour I managed to get the username to automatically populate by adding it to the end of the URL this way.

However, the password does not.

The end goal is to pass this url into a signage system which will display our Power BI Dashboard on a TV. We would need the url to completely enter into the dashboards which require authentication.

This is the url that currently inserts the username. Any ideas?

Thank you

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=871c010f-5e61-4fb1-83ac-98610a7e9110&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dePFJiCiDOs3qi2Vr-JKi64k_4feAKxfsS9Np9g5CJ9yDOMZX0itlFcUfDhStZBlABiKlmiDl6sAFEGKQho9Aa177YpLv778lGFL_eDnrzVAIw_igvcUL3j5aQc1CyJw4aMu03IO95UrL0ZVkDgdaNerK-kU&nonce=635718903066341578.OTUzOGUzOGQtZDZkMS00YjMyLWE5ZjAtYTk0ZTZkODVkYTI2NmFkZDA3ZjUtNDVmYi00NWY3LTlmMjAtNWUzZmUxYTNlZmVk&site_id=500453&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fapp.powerbi.com%2fredirect%2f2&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fapp.powerbi.com%2fredirect%2f2&nux=1&msafed=0&username=USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM&password=PASSWORDHERE
```

Comment: sending a password in the clear is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it is a terrible idea. Do you have any suggestions to be able to authenticate with office 365 and display Power BI dashboards across the organization another way? Thank you

Comment: Did you check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn877545.aspx ?